# JSON Django Model queryset and it's related models

Tags: json, django, django-views

I have two models on Django 1.9, one has a relationship of FK with the other. I want to generate a JSON of the first model and the second as well, but the queryset only loads the first model.

**models.py**

```
class Header(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description=models.TextField()
    createdBy=models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Detail(models.Model):
    header=models.ForeignKey(Disaster)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=3)
```

On **view.py**

```
def getHeaders(request):

header_rs = Header.objects.all()
response_data = serializers.serialize("json", header_rs)

return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type="application/json")
```

The return I got:

```
[
  {
  "model": "DH_BASE.header",
  "pk": 1,
  "fields":       {
     "title": "Teste",
     "description": "Teste",
     "createdBy": 1
     }
   }]
```

I would like the "Detail" to appear in this result as well.
How could I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialization built into django is flat. That means it will only reference related models. You can use natural keys to overcome this, but this is a bit hackish.

Better approach is to use serializers from [Django REST Framework](http://django-rest-framework.com).